# How to add an application bar to a user control in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have built a wizard style user control that lets you add stackpanel based pages and flick between them.

I would like to add an application bar as part of the user control with next and previous buttons that enable/disable based on page displayed etc.

Application bar appears to be an attached property of PhoneApplicationPage. I have tried referencing Microsoft.Phone.Shell but get invalid type.

Any ideas how I can add it to my user control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application bar is such a pain in the a**. This control is not a Silverlight one but a native one. Maybe you can be more lucky with this solution:
http://blog.humann.info/post/2010/08/27/How-to-have-binding-on-the-ApplicationBar.aspx

Comment: Do you use this yourself? How do you use the button binding? WP7 does not support command binding.

Comment: I use the MVVM toolkit: http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/ and bind some text and command on the applicationbar. I was not able to bind an Icon.

Answer (score 2):

The `ApplicationBar` is a service that is provided by the operating system, i.e. not part of the Framework, and can only be used at the page-level, not in your `UserControl`. In addition, the `ApplicationBar` does not support regular bindings as you've seen. As mentioned above there are a number of solutions that provide workarounds for this problem.

Alternatively, you could use the `ApplicationBarButtonCommand` and `ApplicationBarButtonNavigation` behaviors from the [Silverlight Windows Phone Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com). It's a simple enough task to create your `ApplicationBarMenuCommand` if you need one.