# Use mvvm-light CustomEvent Trigger with ApplicationBarIconButton

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

The sample code below for a button will trigger opening of a second page.

```
            <Button x:Name="btnSelect" Content="Select" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,8,20,6" 
                Grid.Row="2" Width="200">
            <Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
                <Custom:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand x:Name="btnSelectClicked" 
                                                               Command="{Binding SelectEventPageCommand, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </Custom:EventTrigger>
            </Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Button> 

    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void ContentGrid_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register<GoToPageMessage>(this, (action) => ReceiveMessage(action));
    }

    private object ReceiveMessage(GoToPageMessage action)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("/Views/");
        sb.Append(action.PageName);
        sb.Append(".xaml");
        NavigationService.Navigate(
           new System.Uri(sb.ToString(),
                 System.UriKind.Relative));
        return null;
    }
}
```

http://galasoft.ch/mvvm/getstarted/

Can anyone suggest how I can do the same using an ApplicationBarIconButton? I get an error Property 'Triggers' is not attachable to elements of type ApplicationBarIconButton.

Or should I just use CodeBehind?

```
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="False">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Button 1">

        </shell:ApplicationBarIconButton>

    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeap ApplicationBar is a little bit different fom other controls in Silverlight. I was able to use an ICommand by using this one:
http://blog.humann.info/post/2010/08/27/How-to-have-binding-on-the-ApplicationBar.aspx

or the Silverlight toolkit which offers some extensions as stated in this answer:
[How to add an application bar to a user control in wp7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810743/how-to-add-an-application-bar-to-a-user-control-in-wp7/4814311#4814311) but I never used it.

Comment: Thanks Matthieu, the first link (http://blog.humann.info/post/2010/08/27/How-to-have-binding-on-the-ApplicationBar.aspx) gives me just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The `ApplicationBar` is a service that is provided by the operating system, i.e. not part of the Framework, and doesn't support `Triggers` as you have already discovered.As mentioned above there are a number of solutions that provide workarounds for this problem.

Alternatively, you could use the `ApplicationBarButtonCommand` and `ApplicationBarButtonNavigation` behaviors from the [Silverlight Windows Phone Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com). It's a simple enough task to create your `ApplicationBarMenuCommand` if you need one. In your case, for using an `ApplicationBar` button to navigate to a page, then the `ApplicationBarButtonNavigation` behavior will do the trick.